# Generic String including digits formatting for RTL & LTR

Tags: ios, swift, localization, right-to-left, nslocalizedstring

I'm facing problem in formatting my strings for RTL & LTR Languages, following is the code

```
let nameEn = "English"
let obtained = 40
let offStr = "Out of"
var messageOne = String.localizedStringWithFormat("%@ %d %@ %d",nameEn,obtained,offStr,obtained+10)
let nameAr = "الإنجليزية"
let offStr2 = "بعيدا عن المكان"
let messageTwo = String.localizedStringWithFormat("%@ %d %@ %d",nameAr,obtained,offStr2,obtained+10)
```

result in messageOne

> English 40 Out of 50

and for messageTwo it is 
[image]

but expected output is

> الإنجليزية 40 من أصل 50

Any guess how Can I achieve that? I tried using unicode for RTL \u{200F}, it fixes problem for RTL but LTR gets disturbed by this, Is there a generic way to do this ?

Comment: See my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38848130/combine-two-language-text

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya I've already tried solution mentioned there, if I use `\u{200F}` in my formatting, then RTL output string out is fine, but it disturbs english & other LTR languages, I want a generic method for matting.

Comment: You should create fuc in appdelegate which returns  \u{200F},  for  RTL  and \u{200E}, for LTR in both cases you have to add some unicode

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya that's what am doing right now, but I'm curious to find a generic way if there is any.