# how to force LTR in label ios

Tags: ios, swift

In the app I have to set the text based on a certain condition. I have the following texts

```
var youTagged = "You Tagged 123 for 456"
var taggedYou = "123 Tagged you for 456"
```

where **123** is gonna be replaced by Person's name and **456** with subject

Everything is working fine except when the person's name is in RTL based language.

**In normal**

it's getting replaced as

> You Tagged Jack for "Sa"
>
> or
>
> Jack Tagged you for "Sa"

**in problematic** case

> Tagged you for "Sa"ג'ֵק

**the name is getting at the end of the string.**

code:

```
var returnString = "" //text based on condition

returnString = returnString.replacingOccurrences(of: "123", with: name)
returnString = returnString.replacingOccurrences(of: "456", with: "\"\(tag)\"")
```

Comment: Check my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38848130/combine-two-language-text-rtl-ltr

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya thanks buddy. Would you like to post an answer so that i can vote and accept the answer

Comment: Shahil it would be duplicate answers !! , So you can upvote that answer and should delete your question. if you think then you can upvote my question too. :)