# C# custom ListView design

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, listbox

I want to display a list of items shown in this image:[[image: image]]

I have searched on the internet how to achieve this. I saw that you can use a ListView and a ListBox. My problem is that I don't know how to change the design of a ListView or ListBox, or that it is even possible to have design like this. Can someone please explain of this design is possible and if so, how to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: WinForms is quite a dated Display Technology. Your sample looks like it is a Mobile or Windows Metro App. Their modern design environments have better support for such modern approaches. | We also need to see some code. Stuff like the instances you try to display, for example.

Comment: If you'd like to read [Make an OwnerDraw ListView in C#](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2016/08/make-an-ownerdraw-listview-in-c/) and many more examples out there.

Comment: Mimicking the __look__ is not so hard by owner-drawing the ListView. There are quite a few examples around.. But:Before you do that make sure you the specs ready for the __behaviour__!!

Comment: In addition to a custom draw `ListView` or `ListBox`, you can achieve this UI using a [`DataRepeater`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb894815(v%3Dvs.140)?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) as well. Another option is using a `WebBrowser` control to show HTML. You can easily have [interaction between WebBroswer control and the Form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34840461/3110834), you can also generate the HTML view using a [T4 run-time template](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/run-time-text-generation-with-t4-text-templates?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=vs-2019).

Comment: Here in an HTML example of [search and showing data in a grid in `WebBrowser` control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54675974/3110834) and using T4 template to generate the grid in html easily.